# django restframework: Why do I get non_field_errors on FK fields with depth=1?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Following API setup with django restframework:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    encoding_job = models.ForeignKey(EncodingJob, blank=True, null=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True, null=True)


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'video', VideoViewSet)

class VideoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    queryset = Video.objects.all()

class VideoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
```

Works fine, but I want the related models to be serialized as well, so I add 'depth = 1' or encoding_job = 'EncodingJobSerializer()' to the serializer.

Now when I look (GET request) at the list of video objects on the Browsable API which includes a create form at the end, it shows 'non_field_errors' below the FK/M2M field inputs. The nested serialization works fine.

[image: screenshot of form below serialized records]

Can someone explain what I do wrong? It seems like it's giving me form validation errors when it should only display an empty form.

Django 1.5.5

djangorestframework 2.3.13

Comment: I assume having a non-readonly viewset with custom serializers for nested objects is not supported, see here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-rest-framework/vCl2I_EzJnE/qwRdIdxiUe4J

Comment: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/395